# Run DXA Resolver with SDL Web 8.5?

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-net, dxa2.2

We are running SDL Web 8.5 with DXA .Net 2.2 and having issues running DXA Resolver. When opening the publish dialog and clicking the button “Show items to publish” an error notification appears, referring to SDL Web 9.

When removing the Sdl.Web.DXAResolver.Resolver"(version=2.2.0.4) from resolvers in Tridion.ContentManager.Config the error message disappears, but then the DXA resolver is disabled.

Any idea how to run the DXA Resolver with SDL Web 8.5?

Edit, adding error message details:

The error in CME notifications is:

```
Unable to retrieve the list of publishable items for item(s) with id tcm:91-90259-64 
Could not load file or assembly Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Looking in EventLog on server gives a stack trace of the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
    Errorcode: 0
    User: ******
    StackTrace Information Details:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.GetResolversFromConfiguration(IEnumerable`1 itemTypes)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.ResolveEngine.ResolveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, ResolveInstruction instruction, IEnumerable`1 contexts)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.ResolveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, ResolveInstruction instruction, IEnumerable`1 contexts, ReadOptions readOptions)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.ResolveItems(IEnumerable`1 ids, ResolveInstructionData resolveInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targetsOrPurposes, ReadOptions readOptions)
       at SyncInvokeResolveItems(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
       at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: I find it odd that if you are truly using SDL Web 8.5 you get an error referring to SDL Web 9. I would double check your setup to confirm the versions you are working on and to ensure that the versions on the different parts of the system are compatible with each-other.

Comment: What is the exact error you get (also check the Windows event logs)?

Comment: Thaks for responses. 
We are looking into the setup and configurations without any luck so far. I do not see “who” is referring to SDL Web 9. 
I have added error details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the DXA 2.2 resolver is built against SDL Tridion Sites 9.0 API, so it can’t be loaded on a SDL Web 8.5 system.

Frankly, I’m flabbergasted, because I’m quite sure that DXA 2.2 has been tested against SDL Web 8.5.

This should be reported as a DXA 2.2 defect.

It should be possible to work around this issue by putting *assembly binding redirects* in your `machine.config`. You can find examples of such assembly binding redirects here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Web.config

Comment: You are so right! 
I have added assembly binding redirects in my machine.config. However the DXA Resolver uses regions, introduced in SDL Web 9 so it still doesn't work.

I think the solution for me is to build a custom version (or an old version) of the Sdl.Web.DXAResolver project on GitHub 
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/tree/master/Sdl.Web.DXAResolver

Comment: Hmmm. You could use this version instead of building your own: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/releases/tag/DXA_2.0.1_Hotfix

Comment: After installing the 2.0.1 version and removing the 2.2 assembly from GAC, now DXA Resolver seems to work as expected. Thank you for the help!